# How to inject function to an existing object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have a simple function. I need to set it to an already existing object. The problem is i dont know how does this work at all. If this is what it is. I need to write a custom function and the third party executes it.

```
var a = [{name: 'yg', sort:'alpha'}, {name: 'pinto'}, {name: 'xyg'}];

defs = $eval(a);
var Fn = function(a, b) {
    return 0;
};

angular.forEach(defs, function(value, key){
    if(value.sort === 'alpha') {
        value.fn =  Fn;
        return value;
    }
});
```

I need def to be:

```
[
  {name: 'yg',
   sort:'alpha', 
   Fn: function(a,b){return 0;}
  }, 
  {
    name: 'pinto'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'xyg'
  }]
```

Here object object contains some but not Fn.

Comment: I suggest you to follow Jihins answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem?

```
var Fn = function(a, b) {
    return 0;
};

angular.forEach(defs, function(value, key){
    if(value.sort === 'alpha') {
        value.fn =  Fn;
    }
});
```

Comment: if i pass a string , the object is set but it doesnt take function, the problem is there

Comment: I edited my answer, I simply want to assign an object literal with a function.

Comment: Possibly you don't see this function property because by default function properties are not iterated when you try to print your object somewhere. But it doedn't mean that this object have no your property. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eoyx9my1/

Answer (score 0):

Refer this http://plnkr.co/edit/10s1laGm66ggkyNk9eao?p=preview

```
var Fn = function(a, b) {
    alert(a+','+b);
    return 0;
  };

  var defs = [{name: 'yg', sort:'alpha'},{ name: 'pinto' },{ name:'xyg' }];
  angular.forEach(defs, function(value, key){
    if(value.sort === 'alpha') {
      defs[key]["Fn"] =  Fn;
      defs[key]["Fn"](1, 2);
      defs[key]["some"] =  'somestring';
    }
  });
```